# split method- null pointer exception generated

Tags: java, split, nullpointerexception

I've written a code to calculate the no of factors of a given list of elements.
INPUT:
test- no of test cases
num- no of elements in 1 test case
numarr- string in which the values(whose product's factors are to be found) is divide by spaces.

When input is:

- 3
- 3
- 3 5 7
- 3
- 2 4 6
- 2
- 5 5
  Ideally, the output should be
- 8
- 10
- 3

But, Exception is:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Main.main(Main.java:31)


import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int test = 0;

        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (scn.hasNextLine())
            test = scn.nextInt();
        int op = 0;
        int[] out = new int[test];
        while ((test <= 100) && (test > 0)) {
            int num = 0;
            if (scn.hasNextLine())
                num = scn.nextInt();
            if (num <= 10) {
                String numarr = null;
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                if (sc.hasNextLine())
                    numarr = sc.nextLine();

                String splitt[] = null;
                if (numarr != null)

                splitt = numarr.split(" ");                           <--ERROR!!!
                if (splitt.length == num) {
                    double[] arr = new double[splitt.length];
                    int i = 0;
                    while (i < splitt.length) {
                        arr[i] = Double.parseDouble(splitt[i]);

                        ++i;
                    }

                    i = 0;
                    double prod = 1;
                    while (i < arr.length) {
                        prod *= arr[i];
                        ++i;
                    }

                    double[] factor = new double[100000];
                    int value = 0;
                    pfac(prod, factor);
                    for (i = 0; (i < factor.length) && (factor[i] != 0); ++i) {

                        value += 1;
                    }

                    out[op] = value;
                    op++;
                }
            }

            --test;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < op; ++i) {
            System.out.println(out[i]);
        }

    }

    private static void pfac(double n, double[] factor) {
        int pos = 0;

        long max = (long) Math.sqrt(n);

        for (long i = 1; i <= max; ++i) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                factor[pos] = i;
                pos += 1;
                if (n / i != i) {
                    factor[pos] = n / i;
                    pos += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: are you sure that the indicated line is the one with npe?

Comment: I formatted your code but even before, line 31 wasn't the one you indicated. Can you double-check where the NPE was at? Though most likely developerwjk's answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what your code is doing:

```
if(numarr!=null)
    splitt=numarr.split(" ");
if(splitt.length==num)
{
...
}
```

If numarr is null you aren't doing the split, which means splitt is still null when you start using it.

Put the whole thing in {}.

```
if(numarr!=null)
{
    splitt=numarr.split(" ");
    if(splitt.length==num)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line you indicate can't throw an NPE, since the preceding `if` statement protects that from ever happening. In the cases where `numarr` is `null` however, you will get an NPE on the next row:

```
if (splitt.length==num)
```

I would guess this is a case of you thinking the `if` statement is covering the next row too. It is good practice to always use curly braces in your `if` statements, to clearly mark where they end.

Comment: @Keppil - Sorry I posted this response into the wrong answer. My apologies. Deleting the comment now.